# Why "file ./-" works but "file .-" does not

Tags: linux

I was solving[text](https://overthewire.org/wargames/bandit/bandit2.html) for linux,and I found i can find files that starts its name with '-'.
So I solved this problem with 'cat ./-',which gets - as filename.
But what I'm wondering is the reason why using '.-' instead of './-; doesn't work.
Since i'm not just a beginner to linux,this question might be dumb,but i really gotta know why.

i thought .- and ./- is just the same,but only file ./- works and file .- show up error that it can't find the file named '.-'

Comment: It's to do with arguments to programs being prefixed with `'-'` and therefore being interpreted as parameters and not literally. You can get around this by terminating your *actual* parameters to the program with `'--'`. e.g. `touch -- -dashstart;ls -- -*`